# Circular motion - object sliding down a hemisphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, reference-frames, free-body-diagram

Suppose that we have a hemisphere, centered on a vertical axis, at the top of which there is an object of mass $m$.

I want to understand how to construct a free body diagram after some arbitrary time $t$ that has elapsed since the object started sliding (but not fallen off yet). (We can define $\theta $ as the acute angle between the radius vector and the axis).

I am concerned about the following:

Initially, I made a blunder by assuming that the normal force $N$ (in the same axis as the radius vector) is equal to $mgcos\theta$. I understand that this is wrong simply because this implies that the centripetal force, $F_c$ is 0 and hence that there is no circular motion which is false. **However, this then led to me wondering: "Doesnt this then violate Newton's Third law?" As a non zero centripetal force implies that the force exerted by the object on the surface of the sphere ($mgcos\theta$) is now not equal to the normal force $N$ that the sphere exerts on the object (hence the force pair doesnt sum up to zero).**

What have I done wrong here? I think that the assumption that the only force the ball exerts on the sphere is $mgcos\theta$ might be wrong, but I dont know why. Perhaps I am misunderstanding what is meant by the term "centripetal force". (I've always been told to treat it as a simple sum of all the resultant forces).

[EDIT]:

Suppose that the ball is now stationary, and $\theta$ non zero. (Friction is now non-negligible). Is my reasoning now valid?

Comment: This is a standard problem, asked many times on Physics SE. See "Related" and links therein. Do some research.

Answer (score 0):

The sphere is sliding on the surface with velocity $v=\omega R$ where $\omega$ is the angular velocity and $R$ the radius of the emisphere.

If the sphere is sliding attached to the emisphere, at any point

$$m\textbf{g}-\textbf{N}=m{\textbf{v}^2\over R}$$

you should split the force in two components and only the radial one is accelerating the particle. It includes the normal force and part of gravity. By imposing that such forces accelerate (i.e. writing $F=ma$ for a rotating object):

$$mg\cos(\theta)-N=m{\textbf{v}^2\over R}$$

so that

$$N=mg\cos(\theta)-m{\textbf{v}^2\over R}$$

you were going in the right direction, but you have to impose rotation (i.e. the term $m{\textbf{v}^2\over R}$).

Notice that if (somehow) the particle is static, it reduces to the well known $$N=mg\cos(\theta)$$.

Since rotations are possible only as long as the normal force allows rotation, the particle will slide only if:
$$N>0$$

i.e.

$$\cos(\theta)>{v^2\over gR}$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand that I initially forgot to impose rotation. However, I dont know what to do about the part which I've emphasized in bold (edit 2) as it really does seem that Newtons 3rd law is being violated here.

Comment: Of course there is NO violation. The two forces (normal and gravity) add up to zero *only* if the particles is still, and you clearly see it putting $v=0$. Otherwise "part" of the total force is used to accelerate centrifugally the object, so the sum is not zero.
There are two ways to see it:
1- In the object's frame of reference: consider the centrifugal force as a fictitious force. Then $mg+N+F_c=0$ and in the object's frame of reference the object is still as expected.
2-Using $F=ma$ with $a={v^2\over R}$ so that $mg+N=m{v^2\over R}$. It shows how the forces generate an acceleration.